# Save error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: MAP<String,AcctId__c>

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm trying to get over a limitation in Salesforce where Lead objects can't have related lists that convert with the Lead over to Opportunity, Contact and Account. I have set up 4 objects of type Lookup Relationship, and created a dummy record in each.

I want to use Custom Settings to store the id of each of these dummy records, so that when the Lead converts, any custom objects can also convert to objects with Master/Detail relationships on the respective standard objects.

My trigger on Lead(after update) tries to create a Map of the Custom Settings:
Map  cs = AcctId__c.getAll();

AcctId__c is the Custom Setting api name. Compile time is giving me the above message.
Now, I copied this code directly from the Salesforce documentation. What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you must include the actual map definition `<String,AcctId__c>` after the word Map.

Check out this page.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm